# Element-Plus Input component for Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, input, autosize, v-model, element-plus

When autosizing an input (textarea) I’ve created with Element Plus for Vue 3, a new line is created before the text reaches the end of the line being typed. This makes the input box unnecessarily large, and there’s unneeded white space after the text.

[Here's a video demo of the issue](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jk9gjwe9rchqsel/AutoSizeIssue3.mov?dl=0)

Here's my code for the component:

```
<template>
        <el-input
                :autosize="{ minRows: 1, maxRows: 16 }"
                type='textarea' 
                :input-style="{
                        
                        border: '0px',
                        fontSize: 'large',
                        paddingTop:'15px',
                        paddingBottom:'15px',
                        borderRadius:'0',
                        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                        minWidth: '100%'                      

                }"
                
            />
 
</template>

<script>


</script>

<style>

</style>
```

And here's the docs
https://element-plus.org/en-US/component/input.html

Any ideas how to fix? Thanks.

Comment: When I add your code into an empty project (with a v-model) attribute it works. Are there extra spaces being added to the model? - Try adding a 'watch' (https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#basic-example) and log the model to see if anything strange is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a "row" attribute to your component

```
  <el-input
    v-model="textarea"
    :rows="2" //This will keep your textarea at the same height
    type="textarea"
    placeholder="Please input"
  />
```